# Нахождение максимума и минимума из двух целых чисел

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, мне нужно сравнить 2 введенных с клавиатуры числа, допустим, M1 и M2. Сравнить их между собой и выдать текст: «Число  M1 > M2» или «Число  M1 < M2».
Вот что я сделал :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int max, min;

    // настаиваем консоль на вывод кириллицы
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    // название программы
    printf("программа для сравнения чисел .n");

    // получаем данные от пользователя
    printf("nВведите первое число: ");

    printf("nВведите второе число: ");
    if (a > b)
        printf("max=%dn", a)
            else
        (b > a) printf("max=%dn", b);

    // выводим результат на экран
    printf("nМаксимальное число  %dnn", max);

    return 0;

}
```

Но не работает. в чем косяк?

Comment: Основной косяк в том, что надо компилировать компилятором перед тем, как задавать подобные вопросы. Тогда их можно будет формулировать более точно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли считать числа с консоли:

```
// получаем данные от пользователя
printf("\nВведите первое число: ");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("\nВведите второе число: ");
scanf("%d", &b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок 3:

1. Не происходит считывания введенных пользователем чисел `a` и `b`.
2. Нигде не вычисляется `max`.
3. В конце условия `if` не стоит `;`.

Answer (score 0):

у вас отсутствует само чтение a & b:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
scanf("%d", &b);
```

затем в if-else, если хотите проверить в else, что b>a - допишите if после else:

```
else if(b > a)
```

и переменная max, у вас остаеться не инициализированной, в ветках выполнения if, произведите присваивание значения нужной переменной max:

```
if(a > b) { max = a; ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a>b ) printf("max=%d\n",a) 
else  (b>a) printf("max=%d\n",b);
```

Синтаксически не верно. После else не может быть условия.

```
if (a > b) ....
else ....
```

Если нужно условие в else, то это делается так:

```
if (a > b) ...
else if (a == b)...
else ...
```